# How to describe the state of a locked door

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the grammar behind saying what seems like a simple thing, but is proving to be hard for me. "The door is locked." In English it's an expression of state using an adjective.

However, research on  鎖 has not been very fruitful as it is apparently just a noun (actually it *can* act as a verb, my bad). The most consistent examples of "the door is locked" I have been able to understand from Jukuu have indicated this structure:

門上了鎖。

First, is this correct? If so, what is the grammatical breakdown? I haven't run across a structure like this before, it doesn't fit a result complement or any other complement structure I know.

It seems like 上 is the verb. Is this the same sense as its use in 上廁所？  I'm also confused by the 了。Is it indicating change? Completion?

Comment: It can work as a verb (门锁了没有，门锁好了). Check out these [many example sentences](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=The+door+is+locked)

Comment: That's funny, I didn't get those when in searched! Thanks! Maybe I had a typo. In any case though, is the sentence in the question also correct?

Comment: Dunno dude, I'm not a native speaker. Both "门上了锁" and "门上锁了" have lots of hits on google, but the latter sounds better to me.

Comment: 門是鎖著的。
門鎖著。
門已上鎖。
門已經鎖了。
門被鎖了。
門被鎖上了。
門鎖了。
門上鎖了。
門鎖好了。

Comment: @SLS Those are great - I wrote them all down!

Comment: door is locked: 门锁上了，is closed 门关上了, in this case note 上 functions as 补语complement (of 趋向direction,结果result) cf. ＂实用现代汉语语法＂第５４９页，［上］  **１。趋向意义（一）**  ：表示人或物体，通过动作由低处向高处移动，没有确定的立足点。例如：（１）龙梅把羊赶上山。说这句话时，立足点（比如说话人的位置）可以在＂山上＂，也可以在＂山下＂（＂下进、出、回。。。＂等也都没有确定的立足点，下文不再说明）。（２）气球慢慢飞上天空。 **２。趋向意义（二）**  ：表示通过动作，人或物体向立足点移动---趋近立足点。例如：（１）老王叫我，我就快步走上前问他有什么事。 **３。结果意义（一）---基本结果意义**  ：表示接触、附着以至固定。例如：（１）请你把门关上。（２）我用一块布把电视机蒙上了。（３）去年我出差到重庆，正赶上八月十五。

Comment: （４）今天外边很冷，把大衣穿上吧。（５）我今天一出门就遇上了一场大雨。（６）前边有一个虫子，小心别踩上。（７）请在卡片上写上你的名字。（８）冰箱温度太低了，牛奶都冻上冰了。（９）他把电脑拆了，自己又装上了。（１０）他看上了那个女孩，可是那个女孩觉得他比不上她以前的男朋友。**４。结果意义（二）**  ：表示实现了预期或希望达到的目的。例如：（１）他终于买上了他喜欢的汽车。（２）我弟弟去年好不容易考上了大学。（３）这个村子的居民去年才用上水。（４）他借了很多钱，一直还不上。＂上＂的这个结果意义是一种口语用法， **５。状态意义**  ：表示动作或状态的开始。例如：
（１）老师刚说了一句话，学生们就议论上了。（２）小明，我叫你睡觉，你怎么又喝上了。（３）这个孩子时间抓得很紧，刚下课回到家，又用上功了。（４）你不是在上学吗，怎么做上生意了？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘门上了锁’ is correct.

I think you can best understand '上' here as 'put, set'.

[Here](http://www.zdic.net/z/14/js/4E0A.htm) there are 16 different definitions for 上：
8，11，13 and 14 approach the meaning here.

门上了锁 door set lock = the door has been locked = the door is locked

If there is a padlock on a door, it is also locked. (padlock is 挂锁）

'门上了锁。' could mean 'There is a padlock on the door.' or 'The door is locked.' or 'The door has been locked.' or even '(someone) put a padlock on the door.' depending on context.

'房门上锁是为了防盗。' was translated: 'The doors were padlocked to prevent theft.'

都可以：

门锁了。The door is locked. / There is a padlock on the door.
门被锁了.
门上了锁。
门锁上了。
门（被）上锁了。

*门（被）锁了上。 【不好】

Comment: It makes so much sense when you break it down like that.  Thanks!  上 is one of those things I'm still getting a good grasp on (plus being able to treat 鎖 as a verb helps).

Answer (score 1):

[上](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/56/) *[6] [v] fit; install; apply; put on*

> 門 - door(indirect object)
>
> (被)上了 - (is) applied(v)
>
> 鎖 - lock (direct object)
>
> "門（被）**上**了鎖" = "door **is applied** with lock"
>
> *It means either a lock is put on the door or the door lock is set to locked state*

~

> 門 - door(object)
>
> (被）鎖上了 - (is) locked(v)
>
> "門（被）鎖上了" = "door is locked"

~

> 門 - door(object)
>
> 是 - is (v)
>
> 锁著的 - locked (adj)
>
> "門是锁著的" = "door is locked"

~

> 锁著的 - locked (adj)
>
> 門 - door(n)
>
> "锁著的門" = "locked door"